# Многопоточность в простом серверном приложении на Python

Tags: python, многопоточность, сетевое-программирование

Есть следующий код:

```
import socket
import threading


def clearip():
    ips.clear()


def clearpatch():
    with open("C:\\Users\\HUMAN\\Desktop\\RUS\\Vars.txt", "r") as fstate:  # changing number of patch alerts in the file
        fcont = fstate.read()
    fcont = fcont.replace("patch_alerts = " + str(state["patch_alerts"]),
                          "patch_alerts = " + 0)
    with open("C:\\Users\\HUMAN\\Desktop\\RUS\\Vars.txt", "w") as fstate:
        fstate.write(fcont)
    state["patch_alerts"] = 0
    patchips.clear()


state = {"patch_alerts" : 0}

ips = {}
patchips = {}

#t1 = threading.Timer(60 * 59, clearip) #every 59 minutes dict ips should be cleared                 #failed experiments with timer
#t1.start()

#t2 = threading.Timer(60 * 60 * 24, clearpatch) #every day dict with ips who alerted the patch is cleared
#t2.start()

while True:
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.bind(('', 9090))
    sock.listen(10)
    conn, addr = sock.accept()

    print('connected:', addr)

    if addr[0] not in ips:
        print("Not in ips")
        ips[addr[0]] = 0 #init number of incorrect requests

    passw = conn.recv(1024)
    if passw != b"6hdt13g": #checking if it's our program
        conn.send(b"Password is not correct")
        ips[addr[0]] += 5
        conn.close()
    else:
        conn.send(b"Password correct")
        while True:
            if ips[addr[0]] > 10:
                conn.send(b"Too many requests") #trying to protect the server
                break
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if data == b'req state': #reading translation characteristics
                with open("C:\\Users\\HUMAN\\Desktop\\RUS\\Vars.txt", "rb") as fstate:
                    cstate = fstate.read()
                    conn.send(cstate)
            elif data == b"addto key": #checking the key
                reckey = conn.recv(1024)
                print(reckey)
                keyfound = 0
                with open("C:\\Users\\HUMAN\\Desktop\\RUS\\Keys.txt", "rb") as fkeys:
                    ckeys = fkeys.read()
                    keysarray = ckeys.split(b";")
                    print(keysarray)
                    for key in keysarray:
                        key = key.strip()
                        if reckey == key:
                            key += b";"
                            ckeys = ckeys.replace(key, b"")
                            print(ckeys)
                            keyfound = 1
                if keyfound == 1:
                    conn.send(b"Key correct")
                    ips[addr[0]] += 1
                    with open("C:\\Users\\HUMAN\\Desktop\\RUS\\Keys.txt", "wb") as fkeys:
                        fkeys.write(ckeys)
                else:
                    conn.send(b"Key not correct")
                    ips[addr[0]] += 2
            elif data == b"alert patch":
                if addr[0] not in patchips:
                    with open("C:\\Users\\HUMAN\\Desktop\\RUS\\Vars.txt", "r") as fstate: #changing number of patch alerts in the file
                        fcont = fstate.read()
                    fcont = fcont.replace("patch_alerts = " + str(state["patch_alerts"]), "patch_alerts = " + str(state["patch_alerts"] + 1))
                    with open("C:\\Users\\HUMAN\\Desktop\\RUS\\Vars.txt", "w") as fstate:
                        fstate.write(fcont)
                    conn.send(b"Patch alert considered")
                    patchips[addr[0]] = 1
                    state["patch_alerts"] += 1
                else:
                    conn.send(b"You already sent patch alert")
            elif data == b"close con":
                break
            else:
                conn.send(b"Unknown command")
                ips[addr[0]] += 3
        conn.close()
    print(ips)
    print(state)
    print(patchips)
```

Раз в 24 часа нужно очищать словари с ip адресами. Как это реализовать так, чтобы при этом работал остальной код? Думал сначала, что таймер поможет, потом оказалось, что он одноразовый. Если же его в цикл бесконечный ставить, то на этом месте программа остановится. Помогите пж (новичок в питоне)

Comment: А что не делалось через BaseTcpServer?

Comment: На ПХП то есть?

Comment: на питоне https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#SocketServer.TCPServer

Comment: опечатался чуток. просто сок.ацепт сто лет не видел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поток типовой с таргетом - простое решение. `daemon` - для того чтоб приложение завершалось при остановке главного. `target` - указатель на фоновую функцию.

```
import threading

def clearip():
  while True:
    time.sleep(86400)
    ips.clear()

t = threading.Thread(target=clearip)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает.